# Why I'm getting Exception-ACS50012: Authentication failed from Azure translator API?

Tags: azure

I have used this code:
https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/HTTP-Code-Samples-Archive/blob/master/PHP/TranslateMethod.php

And in the $clientID I added the: "Subscription ID"
And in the $clientSecret I added the: "KEY 1"
And in the $grantType I don't really understand what to add

But it's still not working and I'm keep getting this error.
I attache the screenshot how it's looks on Azure:

[image: clientID]

[image: Key_1]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The code that you're referencing is for the old Translator API in Microsoft Azure DataMarket which will be deprecated in March.

The correct way to get token for the new Translator API in Azure is here.
http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html